Error while finding module specification for '' (ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on '' while trying to find '')
I have a minimal directory with the following structure:

my_project

code

my_code.py


functions

module1.py





The contents of each file are:
## module1.py
def add_three(number):
    return number+3

And
## my_code.py
from functions.module1 import add_three

result_1 = add_three(1)
print(result_1)

In the command line I cd to the my_project directory, then I run python -m code.my_code and I get this:
C:\[my_user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe: Error while finding module specification for 'code.my_code' (ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'code' while trying to find 'code.my_code')
Most answers I've seen for this error suggest not to include the .py extension with the -m flag, but of course I've already done that.
What's funny is if I cd .., change the import to from my_project.functions.module1 import add_three, and run python -m my_project.code.my_code, it runs correctly.

I solved it simply by adding an empty __init__.py file into each subdirectory.

You only need to add a __init__.py in the folder code.
